# JMeter: How to loop until a variable appears in JSON response?

Tags: json, while-loop, jmeter, response

I am trying to create a test case in which I loop through wrong password login attempts until I reach my final attempt.

This is the JSON response for a normal attempt:

```
{"fault": {"code":10020,"code/h":"0x2724","message":"Wrong password ","params": {"className":"VerificationFailed","badLoginCount": 3,"badLoginCountForChgPwd": 0,"maxBadLoginCount": 5}}}
```

This is the JSON response for the final attempt:

```
{"fault": {"code":10020,"code/h":"0x2724","message":"Wrong password ","params": {"className":"VerificationFailed","badLoginCount": 4,"badLoginCountForChgPwd": 0,"isLastTry": true,"maxBadLoginCount": 5}}}
```

The difference lies in the extra `${fault.params.isLastTry}`.

How should I create this `while`-controller?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor) as a child of the request which can return this or that JSON
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Names of created variables: `lastTry`
   - JSON Path Expressions: `$..isLastTry`

     [image]
3. Put the following [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) into the While Controller's "Condition" input:

   ```
   ${__jexl3("${lastTry}" != "true",)}
   ```

   [image]
4. That's it, how While Controller will loop the request until `"isLastTry": true` attribute is found

   [image]